# How to retrieve Registration ID on Android Device in WinDev Mobile 20?

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging, windev

I'm new to WinDev Mobile. In the project that I'm working on, there is a need for implementing Push Notification with use of GCM.

The notification will be sent from PHP script running on our web server.

For this, it is necessary that the mobile app registers with Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) . This seems to work, But I'm getting the Registration ID like this as a String type.

```
!‘‰åpWx£Üx½ZÌì–´äUü;jÚÿ†PÈÂ§#úùrjIìÑtð*æW‹1ç‰Yæµß;Ar‘ýãU»ç
```

I've to do this because I'm not able to send Buffer content to MySQL. For communicating between mobile app and MySQL I'm using c_PHP4WM 7.0 webservice.

In MySQL the field name is pn_reg_no and its datatype is text. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. Rather than editing [solved] messages in the title, please add an answer below, and click the adjacent tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert that string with function `StringToUTF8()`

Comment: Yes, After conversion, I got Reg. ID like APA91bFSvWgWjKuIrv3PWecQlh4oUtjLH6TxZCNUOXIQSAT3IVFjDkvqkcxzr9J3zyUqLthSs1aJ-JL87C108QxCOpYqBHH8UreTC9vOSaKHelhW6jfKyZ73e8efoXt4rSkX_OPPqRAT

Comment: But Now I'm not able to receive the push notification..   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943932/unable-to-receive-push-notification-on-android-app-using-windev-mobile-20)